# Symfony3 / Doctrine MongoDB ODM: other folder than Bundle/Documents?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Is it possible to place your Entity models in a different place than Bundle/Documents in Symfony3?

I had an entity model in Bundle/Documents/Product.php and it was working fine. Then I changed the location to Bundle/Entity/Product and updated the FQCN to reflect that everywhere.

However, I'm now getting the error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
Class 'Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product' does not exist
```

Even though there are no references to that FQCN anywhere in the project. Does this mean it is not possible to use another folder or am I missing some configuration?

Comment: If you *had* it in `Acme\StoreBundle\Documents\Product` and moved it, then `Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product` does not exist any more – isn’t that to be expected? You need to give more context. Where *in your code* does the exception ultimately come from?

Comment: Like I said, I updated the FQCN to reflect the new location / namespace everywhere. There is no reference to the old FQCN anywhere in the project. It's like malarzm said because of the automapping settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving your Documents to a non-standard folder you need to let Doctrine know about this in bundle's configuration, you can refer to [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#mapping-configuration) for more informations.

Also here's part of my configuration for reference:

```
document_managers:
    default:
        mappings:
            Core:
                type: annotation
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../lib/Application/Core/Model"
                prefix: CompanyManager\Application\Core\Model
```